# File converted to Folder

Tags: file-sharing

I have a 3TB external drive connected to my Cisco E4200 router and for some reason one of the files on the disc was converted to a directory.

I´m using this drive for video streaming and I have 2 PC's running Win7 and XBMC.

Is there a way to convert it back to a file?

It was originally an .avi file

Comment: Which file system was the drive using? How did you put the file on there initially? Can you show us the properties of that file in Windows, or a `ls -l filename` from a Linux terminal?

Comment: The file system is NTFS and it was put there via with copy/paste via USB. I plugged the drive to my PC running Win7 and it asked if I wanted to check the disk for errors. It is now doing that so I can´t show you the properties but it just shows up as an empty directory and the properties window agrees.